# How do I see bad guys on Battlefield 3 multiplayer map?

Tags: battlefield-3

I started playing the beta for Battlefield 3 and was expecting the gameplay to be like Call of Duty, but it is markedly different.  I felt like I needed to creep around a lot more and it wasn't obvious to me how I got killed when I got killed (no enemy camera replay).

How do you see where the bad guys are at in BF3 on the map? I could see my own players but couldn't figure out how to see when the other team was firing.

Comment: Battlefield is very different than CoD. Most flame wars start with someone comparing them, but they are vastly different styles of gameplay. CoD features a more 'arcade shooter' style - fast action, run-and-gun, whereas Battlefield attempts to make the game 'realistic' - as realistic as any FPS video game can be. Both good games, but both taking completely approaches to succeed.

Comment: @SSummer - I broadly agree with this, but I'd go further. I'd suggest that you have CoD at one end of the tactical spectrum (arcade focus, small maps, high intensity), and ARMA2 at the other end (milsim - slower, far more thoughtful & tactical and somewhat 'realistic'). The battlefield series sits firmly in the middle. Personally I prefer the ARMA/BF half of the spectrum, but clearly at lot of people like more accessible games like CoD.

Comment: @CJM - you're correct. I didn't mean Battlefield was really "The most realistic FPS ever" - there are others that are more tactical - Counterstrike comes to mind. I've never played ARMA2, though. But I was saying Battlefield 3 is significantly more realistic than CoD

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has [changed a bit for final](http://mp1st.com/2011/10/17/bf3-soldiers-appear-on-the-map-for-a-short-time-when-firing-an-unsuppressed-weapon/).

> However, Ian Torny recently stated, **“To clarify – You will appear on the mini-map for a short time [when you fire an unsuppressed weapon], but you will not be flagged/spotted,”** referencing Fredrick Thylander’s statement, “It makes you light up on minimap for a split second. Add silencer to avoid it.”

This is a global change for all multiplayer modes. Basically they are moving a bit more towards the Call of Duty: Modern Warfare behavior.

Answer (score 9):

The only times you will ever see an opponent on your map is if someone (yourself included) has "spotted" the enemy (default "q" on PC, not sure about console but previously it was "back/select"), or they have fired an unsuppressed weapon very recently.

If someone has spotted an enemy, then they will appear on your map as a small red/orange triangle (or wedge), as well as having a small red triangle above their head.

Team-mates will always appear on your map as cyan triangles.

Comment: Is there a way on the console to get it to show you all the commands you can do?  I guess after the open beta ends this will make more sense as the game will show you how to do things.

Comment: @MichaelPryor I've never played on either console so I have no idea how to show what you're asking.